# Get date by GPS using c-Sharp Xamarin

Tags: c#, java, android, gps, xamarin

I'm trying to get the current date through GPS.

I created the following code:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        locationManager = GetSystemService (Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
        locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GpsProvider, 1000, 1, this);

    }

public void OnLocationChanged (Android.Locations.Location location)
{
    Log.Debug (tag, "Location changed");
    DateTime dt = new DateTime (location.Time);
    txtStatusGPS.Text = dt.ToString ();
}
```

But the current date is coming as follows: 01/02/0001 The hour is coming, it's only going missing for a given region.

Can anyone help me?

I'm tried to format for this code:

```
public void OnLocationChanged (Android.Locations.Location location)
        {
            Log.Debug (tag, "Location changed");
            DateTime dt = new DateTime (location.Time);
            string dataFormatada = String.Format("{0:d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year


            txtStatusGPS.Text = dataFormatada;
        }
```

Then I get in txtStatusGPS: 02 of January of 0001

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat instead of .toString().  SimpleDateFormat is designed to convert a Date into a human-readable form, and understands the Locale.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html